# PCIe v2.0 -> PCIe 3.0 for 10GbE network card?

Tags: pcie, network-adapter

I have scenario where I'm plugging an [Intel X520-DA2](https://ark.intel.com/products/39776/Intel-Ethernet-Converged-Network-Adapter-X520-DA2) into an [Asus Maximus VIII Hero Alpha](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/ROG-MAXIMUS-VIII-HERO-ALPHA/) and at each attempt to post, I get a "55" readout on the motherboard LED.  When I remove the card the system works fine again, but when I insert the card into any of the PCIe 3 slots I receive this LED error and no video output.

Is there some kind of a compatibility issue between the network card and the motherboard that I'm missing?  I've done similar arrangements before with these disparate types of PCIe cards with no problem, but it seems that I'm hitting a wall on this.

Comment: Have you ruled out the card as being the problem?  Also, I suggest you ask over at https://rog.asus.com  as this is a tech support question, which is not on topic here.

Comment: I've tried two identical NICs... I guess my understanding of this being hardware related and this being a hardware section of StackExchange was wrong. Sorry.

Comment: Yeah, what is considered in scope and not in scope can be.........daunting.    Go look at the meta page, it can be quite a read.

Comment: By the way, from what I can tell the 55 error is a memory not installed error, which is intriguing, as this is only happening on your system when you install a wireless card.....

Comment: Right, that is what has baffled me @NZKshatriya.  I can't seem to draw any valid conclusions as such.